# Calculate age from year of birth in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column with multiple values including date of births and year of births

```
ID    OptionValue

1        1992
2        1993-05-31
3        2002
4        1976-06-3
```

Ideally I want the solution to be

```
ID    OptionValue        Age

1        1992            31
2        1993-05-31      29
3        2002            21 
4        1976-06-3       46
```

now

```
Select TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, lp.optionValue , CURDATE())as Age from learner
```

and

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(lp.optionValue , '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(lp.optionValue, '00-%m-%d')) as Age from learner
```

works perfectly well for me when the date format is 'yyyy-mm-dd' but throws an error for when the year is given only. Can I calculate the age from just given year?

Comment: well if your actual birth date has already passed this year then you will be one year older than if it is coming up later this year.  so you cant do it reliably.

Comment: Why is the Age 30 for 1992 and 21 for 2002?

Comment: @forpas sorry you are right, I have changed first one it to 31

Comment: Why is the Age 29 for 1993-05-31? Is it because the current date is before 05-31? If so, then why is the Age 47 for 1976-06-3? You must explain better your requirement.

Comment: Use CASE operator, check the data format, convert year-only values to complete date. Then apply TIMESTAMPDIFF().

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick:

```
Select TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, if(length(lp.optionValue) = 4 , concat(lp.optionValue ,'/01/01'),lp.optionValue), CURDATE())as Age from learner
```